# Why do taller letters appear deformed when rendering text with FreeType in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, glm-math, freetype, opengl-4

I have managed to draw text with FreeType in OpenGL 4, but the taller letters (e.g. g, d, f, etc.) are somehow being drawn too tall. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPrjk.png) [This is what it is supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eb5n.png) The tall letters are too tall, while the "normal height" letters are just fine.

```cpp
struct FontChar {
    float tx; // texcoord x position
    float tw; // texcoord x width
    glm::ivec2 size; // face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows
    glm::ivec2 bearing; // face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top
    glm::ivec2 advance; // face->glyph->advance.x, face->glyph->advance.y
} fontChars[128]; // this is populated properly with FreeType

std::vector<float> vertices;

const float sx = 2.0f / 1920.0f;
const float sy = 2.0f / 1080.0f;

float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
for (char c : text) {
    const float vx = x + fontChars[c].bearing.x * sx;
    const float vy = y + fontChars[c].bearing.y * sy;
    const float w = fontChars[c].size.x * sx;
    const float h = fontChars[c].size.y * sy;
    float tx = fontChars[c].tx;
    float tw = fontChars[c].tw;
    std::vector<float> quad = { // pos_x, pos_y, tex_x, tex_y
        vx, vy, tx, 0.0f,
        vx + w, vy, tx + tw, 0.0f,
        vx + w, vy - h, tx + tw, 1.0f,
        vx + w, vy - h, tx + tw, 1.0f,
        vx, vy - h, tx, 1.0f,
        vx, vy, tx, 0.0f
    };
    vertices.insert(vertices.begin(), quad.begin(), quad.end());
    x += float(fontChars[c].advance.x >> 6) * sx;
    y += float(fontChars[c].advance.y >> 6) * sy;
}
```

I then buffer the vertices into a vertex buffer, and then I draw it. The only code that could affect the height is `const float h = fontChars[c].size.y * sy`, but the size is taken straight from FreeType, and the `sy` works for the "normal height" letters. This leads me to believe that it could be due to the glyph textures being put into a texture atlas.

```cpp
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

std::array<FontChar, 128> characters{};

unsigned int w = 0;
unsigned int h = 0;
for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_BITMAP_METRICS_ONLY)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load glyph");
    }
    w += face->glyph->bitmap.width;
    h = std::max(face->glyph->bitmap.rows, h); // maybe this is the issue???
}

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, w, h, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

unsigned int x = 0;
for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load glyph");
    }
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, 0, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);

    FontChar character = {
        (float)x / (float)w,
        (float)face->glyph->bitmap.width / (float)w,
        glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
        glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
        glm::ivec2(face->glyph->advance.x, face->glyph->advance.y)
    };
    characters[c] = character;

    x += face->glyph->bitmap.width;
}
```

The only other place where I do anything that could influence this vertical stretching behavior is when I find the max height of the characters. I do this so I can find the proper dimensions of the texture atlas, which is just 1 character tall by n characters wide. I'm still not sure how this could cause the behavior though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. My instincts were correct; the issue was related to the height of the texture atlas. I was not plugging the heights of the glyph bitmaps into the actual vertices, I was instead using the entire height of the texture. All I had to do was pass the heights of the characters into the FontChar struct when populating the fontChars array, and then I made my vertices go from 0.0f to the height instead of 0.0f to 1.0f. This worked except now all of my text was too tall. Then I realized that I am using an orthographic matrix which extends the x coordinates from [-1, 1] to [-width/height, width/height], and since I was using separate scale factors (sx and sy), my scaling was incorrect. To fix, I just got rid of sy and replaced every sy with sx. I also added 2 pixels between each texture in the atlas so I don't get any smearing between textures. [Here is the final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX7bE.png)